# Who owns the method in a sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

Say we have the diagram:

[image: Sample sequence diagram]

I wonder whether it's known by the diagram who owns the methods.

For instance: Is `pickup` a method of `Waiter`? Is `serve food` then a method of `Patron`?

More generally, do the arrows show the owners of the methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a counterintuitive (ie bad) choice of method names.

Fred is ordering the food, that's right.  He's ordering the food by calling `takeOrder()`, which belongs to the waiter.  Imagine Frank tries to call `order food` on anyone other than a `waiter`.  It wouldn't work, because they're not waiters, and they don't have `takeOrder()`.

The methods belong to the objects that are being called.